# Doesn't download dependency even if it is correct

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml

I have this dependency in pom.xml:

```
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.9.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Even dependendcy is correct, i got error message: **Missing artifact org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.3.9.Final**

It should be downloaded from central repo, but maven doesn't download it.

Comment: Maybe a network problem? Firewall, Proxy?

Comment: Can you check if the jar is present in the local repositories folder? Are you using the m2e plugin? Last but not the least, did you try searching this site for existing answers? I believe there are a lot of similar questions with good answers already avaialble on this site.

Comment: do you have any special proxy settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened local maven repo: .m2\org\hibernate\hibernate-entitymanager\ ,and **deleted folder**: **4.3.9.FINAL** solved the problem.

**The problem was window's folder case insensitivity issue with maven local repo case sensitive versioning**:

As you can see folder was upper case **4.3.9.FINAL** instead of the correct **4.3.9.Final**.

Maybe when I firstly added the dependency I mistyped to upper case version, then corrected to normal case. Even I corrected it, maven already created a directory with upper case (missing version), and because windows folders are not case sensitive, maven couldn't create a new folder for normal case, so couldn't  download the correct dependency.

Deleting wrong case folder solved the problem as maven could create normal case folder in local repo.

Comment: Thanks budy. I also stuck with the same issue. Reading ur answer I went to `local .m2` & look for `hibernate-core/4.3.9.FINAL` & it is there which causing problem. I **change it to `4.3.9.Final` in `pom.xml` & delete `4.3.9.FINAL` from `local .m2 repo`**. Everything works fine. +1.